# Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'system'

Tags: python, terminal, raspberry-pi, libraries, raspberry-pi-pico

[Error MSG in thonny for windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnQTi.png)

I would love some help with this error or if someone could show me how to accses the terminal in pi pico w. I have been trying now for a couple hours trying to run python code on my raspberry pi pico w and everytime i go search online to check other forums they all use a terminal command but the pi pico does not have a terminal as far as I know.
Thanks in advance.

I was hoping i could find the terminal to install requests

Comment: You're importing both `urequests` and `requests`, and trying to use `requests` — I'm assuming that's a typo if you're on a Pi, because you'll want to be using `urequests` everywhere, right?

Comment: OMG thank you so much! I am so sorry I feel so bad now I just wasted your time. and again THANKS ALOT!!!!